# jQuery in IE not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have the below code on a html5 document but it is not working in IE. It works OK in Chrome but ive read that IE is not so forgiving on scripts and the way they are coded.

I am very new to jQuery so any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
<div class="gallery">

    <div id='gallery-1' class='gallery galleryid-6 gallery-columns-9 gallery-size-thumbnail'>
        <dl class='gallery-item'>
            <dt class='gallery-icon'>
                <a href='http://mysite.co.uk/homepage-01.jpg'><img src="http://mysite.co.uk/01-90x90.jpg" /></a>
            </dt>
        </dl>
        <dl class='gallery-item'>
            <dt class='gallery-icon'>
                <a href='http://mysite.co.uk/homepage-02.jpg'><img src="http://mysite.co.uk/02-90x90.jpg" /></a>
            </dt>
        </dl>
        <dl class='gallery-item'>
            <dt class='gallery-icon'>
                <a href='http://mysite.co.uk/homepage-03.jpg'><img src="http://mysite.co.uk/03-90x90.jpg" /></a>
            </dt>
        </dl>
    </div>

</div><!--gallery-->

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div.gallery a").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("div.picture").html($("<img>").attr("src", this.href).fadeIn(1000));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean?  People on Stackoverflow don't like to guess at these things.

Comment: your right sorry, will bare that in mind in future. It was images showing as thumbnails in one div (.gallery) were linked to their larger image. And the linked larger image should show in another div (.picture) on the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `event` isn't defined it should be:

```
$("div.gallery a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("div.picture").html($("<img>").attr("src", this.href).fadeIn(1000));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "pass" the `event` to your click handler:

```
$("div.gallery a").click(function(event) {    // <---- here
        event.preventDefault();
```

...otherwise `event` is undefined within the click handler.  Referencing it will cause things to break (I'm surprised it works anywhere).